# Equivalence of categories, related to Galois descent

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, group-cohomology, profinite-groups

I'm trying to understand an example (A.64) in the appendix of Milne's 2017 book on algebraic groups. It goes like this.

Let $K/k$ be a Galois extension with Galois group $\Gamma$. We want to show that the functor $V \rightsquigarrow V \otimes_k K$ is an equivalence of categories from $k$-vector spaces to $K$-vector spaces with continuous semilinear $\Gamma$-action.

I understand the argument that Milne gives in the case where $K/k$ is a finite extension. However, right before that, he says, "It suffices to prove this with $K$ a finite Galois extension." I do not understand why this is sufficient. I have spent some time trying to derive the infinite case from the finite case, and am stuck.

I feel like it should be a somewhat straightforward consequence of the Galois correspondence for infinite extensions and the fact that the infinite Galois group is the inverse limit of intermediate Galois groups, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You want to know which $k[\Gamma]$-modules are of the form $V\otimes_k K$ ? For $K/k$ finite Galois then $K\cong k[\Gamma]$ (the isomorphism is given by a normal basis)

Comment: No, I want to know that all $K[\Gamma]$-modules are of the form $V \otimes_k K$. I already know that they are in the case when $K/k$ is finite Galois, and I want to use that to understand why it is true when $K/k$ is infinite.

Comment: $K$ isn't a $K[\Gamma]$-module. It is a $k[\Gamma]$-module.

Comment: I'm still confused. I don't see how this relates to the case when $K/k$ is infinite.